# iOS Date Slider/Selector Used In Stock App

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to produce something like the date picker below? Does anyone know how to / or even what type of element to use? I was thinking a UISlider, but not sure how to customize the slider to show bubbles and such. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

[image: Date Slider]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like **A custom View and graph by [Bezier path](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html)**.

Also you need some help from [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/DrawingEnviron/DrawingEnviron.html).

Those 1d, 1w, 1m, 3m looks like a button or image. Need to write action methods on them.

Comment: I already reproduced the graph using CorePlot. I am just wondering how  to create the date picker (1M, 6M, 1Y, ect). You mentioned custom view. So I would have to create images for the selected elements and then a background image for the whole bar of dates?

Comment: Those 1d, 1w, 1m, 3m looks like a button or image. Need to write action methods on them.

Comment: Aha! You are correct! I added a button for each date, and turned on "Shows Touch On Highlight". Works perfect! Thank you